# using WebApi Controller Ajax (SignalR)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, signalr

I used this [tutorial](http://techbrij.com/database-change-notifications-asp-net-signalr-sqldependency), but I'm not using any MVC framework.

How can I replace a controller or use it in ajax request to get any updated data from SQL table?

```
            $.ajax({
            url: '../ValuesController',
            type: 'GET', ...
```

Comment: its the url to your method

Comment: You replace that `url` with the URL to your server method.

Comment: i tried this: '../ValuesController/Get', but dont find anything
"Get" is the method

Comment: @Jonesy what is wrong?

Comment: @tymeJV what is wrong?